# How to Catch repeated string values in a 2D array and replace it

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I have created a program that rolls a dice twice depending on the amount of rolls that the user inputs. Each two rolls are stored as an x and y value and are inserted into it's corresponding spot in a 2D array. However, I cannot figure out a correct way to catch when the dice rolls duplicate.

**The Array is as such:**

```
String [][] arr =  {
                {"0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"},
                {"0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"},
                {"0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"},
                {"0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"},
                {"0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"},
                {"0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"}
        };
```

If dice output is:
"4 and 4"
"4 and 5"
"4 and 4"

Then the array will appear as:

[2D Array Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAMOP.png)

My current code for inserting these numbers into the 2D array is as follows:

```
    public static String[][] updateArray(String[][] arr, int userInput) {
        for (int rolls = 0; rolls < userInput; rolls++) {
            int roll1 = rollDice(); // x
            int roll2 = rollDice(); // y
            String rolled = roll1 + "," + roll2;
            System.out.println("The dice rolled: " + roll1 + " and " + roll2);
            int xIndex = roll1 - 1;
            int yIndex = roll2 - 1;
            arr[yIndex][xIndex] = rolled; // first value is y second is x
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

What should be happening is that the program should be finding that there is a duplicate number and rerolling ONLY those two specific rolls to get an array that has no duplicates.

I have tried many complex methods, that still do not end up working for me. I believe there is an easier solution. If you need any more clarification for anything let me know.

Comment: Have you tried testing `if (arr[yIndex][xIndex].equals ("0,0"))` ?

Comment: Off-topic: The `String[][] arr` seems to have redundant information.  A `boolean [][] arr` could be used.

Comment: So, if `updateArray` is modified to re-roll when a roll results in a duplicated roll, then calling `updateArray` 36 times will "record" every possible roll, regardless of how many rolls there were, which could be hundreds.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer precisely

Comment: I have to wonder if this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What problem is a solution to this problem intended to solve?

Comment: Why are you using Strings? Why not `int[][] arr = { {0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0} };` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const UserInput = null;
int intNumOfDoubles = null;
int[][] intDiceRollsArr = {
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0},
    {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}
    };

public static int[][] updateArray(int[][] intDiceRollsArr, int userInput) {
for (int rolls = 0; rolls < userInput; rolls++) {

    UserInput = userInput
    int roll1 = rollDice(); // x
    int roll2 = rollDice(); // y
        
    System.out.println("The dice rolled: " + roll1 + " and " + roll2);
    int xIndex = roll1 - 1;
    int yIndex = roll2 - 1;
    intDiceRollsArr[rolls][xIndex] = roll1;
    intDiceRollsArr[rolls][yIndex] = roll2;
}   
   return intDiceRollsArr;
}

public static void CheckDoubles(int[][] intDiceRollsArr){
    boolean boolIsMoreRolled = true;
    while(boolIsMoreRolled == true){
        for(int intCounter = 0; intCounter < UserInput; intCounter++){
            if(intDiceRollArr[intCounter][1] == 0){
                boolIsMoreRolled = false;
            } 
            else{
if(intDiceRollArr[intCounter][0] == intDiceRollArr[intCounter][1]){
                    intNumOfDoubles++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).